# Boot issues i get this screen while I boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, laptop, hp, single-user

[image]

1. I get this screen while booting
2. I need to power of my pc to get rid of this screen sometimes even it won't work
3. I tried reinstalling the os it is not working
   4 Ii tried upgrading it is not working

Comment: Take a look at the linked question above. If that does not help, you should update your question describing the attempted steps to fix and how the above linked question didn't fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a `acpi_backlight=vendor` option to the Grub file. Here’s how:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Open the `/etc/default/grub` file with `sudo` in your preferred text editor
3. Add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` setting. For example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```
4. Save the file and exit
5. Update Grub

   ```
   sudo grub-update
   ```
6. Reboot

You may need to do this via a Live USB if you cannot boot the system at all.

Comment: iam new to this can explain this in detail how to  Open the /etc/default/grub file with sudo